# Converting a Directed Acyclic Graph to a Directed Tree

Tags: graphs, dag, decomposition

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with this. Say I have a DAG, I understand that it has no directed cycles, but it can have loops ( "diamonds" ).
My question is, is there a known way to convert such graph to a directed tree that has no loops. I know of the junction tree/ clique tree way, but this results in an undirected tree  after moralization.

I am trying to decompose a DAG type graph to a more tree-like structure. For context the vertices in the graph represents sinks and sources so there can be multiple sources.

Edit: I should've been more clear. To be more concise, I was wondering if there was a way to convert a DAG to a polytree.

Comment: What if the DAG has multiple sources? Then a tree wouldn’t be doable. If there is only one source and all vertices are reachable from it you can just DFS/BFS from the source and that gives you a tree with the original edge set.

Comment: Please be more precise: what are your restrictions? If you want any tree, just consider a spanning tree of the undirected version of your graph.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response,
@Nathaniel  I should've been more clear, I know how to use get the undircetd spanning tree, but direction is important for my use-case.
I think what I meant to say was to convert a DAG to multitree. I will update my question with an example figure

Answer (score 0):

If the undirected version $G'$ of the DAG $G=(V, E)$ is not connected, then there is no [polytree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree) that contains all vertices in $V$ and only a subset of the edges in $E$.

If $G'$ is connected, then you can compute any spanning tree $T$ of $G'$ and construct the poly-tree that contains all vertices in $V$ plus all the (directed) edges $(u,v) \in E$ such that the (undirected) edge $\{u,v\}$ is in $T$.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying the last part for e please? 
If I understand you correctly, then `T` looks like `G` but without the edges that form a diamond dependencies ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the "edges that form diamond dependencies" are. $T$ is any tree that contains all vertices of $G$ and only *some* of the edges of $G$, where each edge is treated as undirected. In other words $T$ is a subgraph of (the undirected verison of) $G$ that contains all vertices and is both  connected and acyclic.  See [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree). To get a polytree, orient the edges of $T$ along their original direction in $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful breakdown.  For more context I am trying to propagate information between vertices along the directed edges. I will go do some more  reading on spanning trees and test my method on the tree and see if the results I'm getting are a good enough approximation of what I'm expecting. Thank you again